matlab - grey level cocurrence matrix (GLCM)
This is the code , i have tried changing the mathematical equations , logic and values , i have tried all approches but still not ablee to get the correct answer , i want matrix B = Matrix E. given Matrix A is the before transpose of glcm matrix(probability matrix).
so please tell me which approach i should go for so that matrix B == matrix E


% Given GLCM matrix
glcms = [0.17 0.08 0.04 0.0;
         0.08 0.17 0.0  0.0;
         0.04 0.0  0.25 0.04;
         0.0  0.0  0.04 0.0];


%GrayLevel_Co-occurence demo final

%img = imread('SAMPLENODULE1.jpg');


% Convert to grayscale if necessary
%if size(img, 3) > 1
    %img = rgb2gray(img);
%end

I = [0 0 1 1;
    0 0 1 1;
    0 2 2 2;
    2 2 3 3];

A = [2 2 1 0;
    0 2 0 0;
    0 0 3 1;
    0 0 0 1];

D = A';

E = A + D;
E

%glcms = graycomatrix(I);

%glcms
m = 5;
%n = 4;
count = 0;
%count1 = 0;
n = 3;
o = 4;

for i = 1 : 4 

    for j = 1:4 

        for l = 1 : 4 
        for  k = 1 : 4

            x = I(i,1);
           y = I(i,3-1);
           a = I(i,3+1-1);
            b = I(i,2+2-1);
           
            
          if (I(i,j) &&   I(i,n-j)) == (I(i,n-k) && I(i, n+1-k))
              
         
             %disp('Entered the control');
       
      % count = count+ 1;

          %end
          
          
           end

    
        end

        B(i,j) = count;
   
        
    
     

    end

     %B(i,j) =  count;
         
    
    %end
    %end
end

%if (E == B)
  %  disp('Correct Answer');
%else
   % disp('Not Correct Answer');
%end


